# I had an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resetForm')"

Tags: angular, error-handling, null, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I have a method named it onSubmit, this method submits my reactive form.

```
onSubmit(){
    this.comment = this.commentForm.value;
    console.log(this.comment);
    if(this.dishcopy !== null && this.dish !== null){
      this.dishcopy.comments.push(this.comment)
      this.dishService.putDish(this.dishcopy)
        .subscribe({
          next: dish => {this.dish = dish; this.dishcopy = dish},
          error: ermess =>{this.dish = null; this.dishcopy = null; this.errMess = <any>ermess}

        })
    }
    this.commentForm.reset({
      author: '',
      comment_author: '',
    })


    this.commentFormDirective.resetForm()

  }
```

When I enter my value, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCPbd.png) on my form

I have an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUxVg.png)

So I'm not giving up. And I started searching for answers on the internet. I find one answer that I need to add to my

```
this.commentFormDirective.resetForm()
```

like ?

```
this.commentFormDirective?.resetForm()
```

And I got any error except :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NqXr.png)  my error handler

In addition, I show you my error to clarify this:

```
  putDish(dish:Dish): Observable<Dish> {
     const httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       })
     }
     return this.http.put<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + dish.id, dish, httpOptions)
       .pipe(e => this.processHttpMsgService.handleError(e))
  }
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the way you are handling errors in the putDish() method. You are using the pipe operator to pass the error through the handleError() method in the processHttpMsgService. However, the pipe operator expects you to return an observable, but the handleError() method returns an error message as a string. Use the catchError operator instead of the pipe operator.
`.pipe(catchError(e => this.processHttpMsgService.handleError(e))`

Answer (score 0):

Your first error occurs because `commentFormDirective` property is undefined. It should be initialized or injected with constructor if provided somewhere else.

The 404 errors in your console are about missing fonts, it is not related to your API calls.